# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener comunicação com arduíno

Tags: java, arduino, intellij-idea, serial

Estou a tentar fazer uma comunicação java com um arduíno mas estou com um problema quando invoco uma `Class` que implementa o `SerialPortEventListener` no meu controller.

**Controllers**

Esta classe Java é só a que vai tratar da comunicação.

```
public class controllerListener implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public static void writeData() {
        System.out.println("TESTE");
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
        System.out.println("ds");
    }
}
```

Esta é onde a aplicação é iniciada.

```
public class Application extends Controller{

    public static Result index() {
        return redirect("/home");
    }

    public static Result home() {
        controllerListener.writeData();
        return ok(homePage.render());
    }

    public static Result aboutUs() {
        return ok(aboutUs.render());
    }
}
```

Quando corro o programa dá-me o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] 
shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at controllers.Application.home(Application.java:16)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:88)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:88)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more
[ERROR] [11/10/2015 17:59:09.295] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at controllers.Application.home(Application.java:16)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:88)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:88)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more
```

Caso remova a linha `controllerListener.writeData();` do `controller Application` a aplicação inicia sem qualquer erro.

**Versão:** IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4

É lógico que para já não tenho código para fazer a comunicação com o arduíno, só estou a tentar implementar primeiro o `SerialPortEventListener`.
Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda onde poderei estar a falhar? Obrigado

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener`: ou a dependência não está no *classpath* ou a versão é diferente da que usou para compilar.

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela ajuda. Como confirmo se a dependência está no casspath?! Sou novo nestas andanças ...

Comment: Finalmente consegui resolver o problema. Criei uma pasta lib dentro do projeto e importei o .jar de lá. Obrigado @BrunoCésar pela ajuda!